# Django keeps showing loggin form after being logged in

Tags: django, authentication

In a Django project I am using the standard authentication system. The user is redirected to /bewerken/dashboard/, which has two links. One of them is linked to /bewerken/inhoud/. However, when clicking the link, the login form is shown again (at url /bewerken/inhoud/). So, the user logs in and is returnd to /bewerken/dashboard again (because that is the 'next' url). And on and on. Don't know what I'm doing wrong!

The urls.py from the project:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^bewerken/', include('zzpwebsites.apps.user.urls')),
)
```

The urls.py from the app:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^inhoud/$', views.bewerken_inhoud, name='bewerken_inhoud'),
    url(r'^dashboard/$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    url(r'^', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'user/inloggen.html'}),
)
```

And the view:

```
@login_required
def bewerken_inhoud(request):
    Usp_1 = Usp.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    context = ({'usp_1': usp_1,})
    return render(request, 'user/bewerken_inhoud.html' , context)
```

Thanks!

Comment: looks like the user's login is lost between pages. do you have session installed? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/

Comment: @EsseTi: yes, SessionMiddleware and AuthenticationMiddleware are both installed. As are django.contrib.auth and django.contrib.contenttypes.

Comment: try a test: remove `@login_required` from the view and add `print request.user` then run and do a login, then open the inhoud page. what's the output?

Comment: @EsseTi Thanks for the suggestion. Nothing changes however, still getting the login form again..

Comment: if you remove the @login_required it should not check the user's login for displaying the page. there's something wrong then. btw context looks strange to me, you can do it like this `context = {}` then `context['usp_1']=usp_1` . just came to my mind, try this
`return render(request, 'user/bewerken_inhoud.html' , context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

Comment: @EsseTi: The changes in the context and return render have no impact..